# How to use a PHP variable to set width of a progress bar

Tags: php, html

My PHP Code is ready and its working fine on the live server, I want to add a progress bar for showing active server player

Here is the code:

```
echo '
<td class="subsection style="width: 57px;">
    <div class="headline" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">players</div>
    <div style="text-aling: center; font-size: 12px;">'. $userd_slots . '/ '. $availablee_slots . '</div>
</td>';
```

But it's not working

[image]

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $required_percent; ?>%">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: omg you took screenshots of your code...

Comment: please don't use images to show your code just copy paste it

Comment: So what are you stuck on? What research have you done in creating the progress bar?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and formulate your question to fit those guidelines. So far, your question is incredibly broad, and your "screenshots" provided nothing of use to the question. What is your progress bar? How does it work? When you mean width, do you mean adding a simple php variable as a style? `$progressWidth='8';` `<div class=progress-bar style="widht: <?php echo $progressWidth; ?>% !important;"></div>`

Comment: I'm so sorry, actually I'm new in StackOverflow.im apologies for my mistake 
@marti

Comment: I'm apologise for my mistake.
 This is my progress bar code

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:<?php echo $required_percent; ?>%">
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: There is still too little information as to why your code might not be working. We'll need more information to be able to help you. It's like you provide a very small snippet of the application, which in theory, seems fine. But we have no idea of what the PHP vairables contain, or whether it could be a CSS problem etc. If you hardcode a width, does it work? Just for testing purposes. That way you know it's at least not the CSS or HTML that's the problem, but the PHP variable(s).

Answer (score 0):

I will be assuming the maximum number of players will be evolving.

You can use a variable to compute the percentage of fill

```
$perc = ($used_slots * 100) / $available_slots
```

Then, you can echo your progress bar like this

```
<progress value = ".$perc." max = 100></progress>
```